# EMF Modeling question: container and containment

Tags: eclipse, ecore

I'm familiar with Entity Framework and code-first design in Visual Studio, but I'm getting my feet wet with Eclipse.  That said, I'm trying to understand how some of the properties for eReference attributes translate in ecore models.  Specifically, when I read about container and containment, I'm finding myself lost.  Are these fields somehow translatable into either SQL Foreign Key relationships or entity model object relationships?  I can understand both of those pretty well.  Specifically, in either SQL or EF terms, what does it mean when container=true, what does it mean when containment=true.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with SQL or EF, but from what I am reading, Foreign Key is more like EReference (and other fields are EAttribute, with "primary key" being an EAttribute with isID set to true).

Containment in Ecore is a particular case of EReference. The key part is that an EObject can only be contained by one other EObject. I think the best would be for you to just try it out on a simple Ecore metamodel!

Comment: So by one EObject being only contained by another EObject, would this be set on the many side or the one side of the one-to-many reltionship?  For example, customers:orders would be a one-to-many relationship?  I'm assuming that setting this properly would allow an actual object representation of the data and allow me to get (in the example above) an array of order objects from within any one given customer object.

Comment: The containment property is set on an EReference.
An EReference belongs to an EClass (the "departing point" or "containing object" of the EReference, just like in Java you define attributes/references in the class from which the reference departs)
So in that sense, yes the containment in set on the "one" side of the relationship.

A reference from EClass "Customer" to EClass "Order" with multiplicity upper bound of * will give access in a Customer object to a list of Order objects, yes.

"Is the lifecycle of Order items controlled by Customer or not?" determines if this is a containment